# Element is clickable just sometimes

Tags: java, selenium, testing, junit, cucumber

I'm writing a test for a standard form. I have a textbox, date, select.. all kinds of inputs, and at the end, a Reset and Filter button. In Date field, there is always a date by default. I need to press Reset button in order to clear all the fields, and then push Filter button. This way, all "Required Field" messages are shown so I can test them. I had some trouble pushing Reset button so I tried this code:

```
@When("I push Reset Button$")
public void pushReset(){    
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(formOne.resetButton)).click();
```

Here is how I find the element:

```
@FindBy(how = How.NAME, using = "reset_rules")
public WebElement resetButton;
```

And the external HTML to locate it

```
<input name="reset_rules" value="Reset" class="button critical reset none" 
style="margin-right: 10px;" type="reset">
```

So I launch the test, and sometimes Reset Button is pushed and all steps are passed. If I launch it again, Resset button hasn't been pressed. Then I launch it again, it works... Since there are no changes in the DOM, CSS, HTML or similar, I have no idea what's going on

Any help? Thanks in advance

Comment: Update the question with the relevant _HTML_

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things to think about.

Open up a web browser and check that //*[@name='reset_rules'] only returns 1 match.

Also most of the time when something runs in a flaky manner like this, there's some poor wait logic prior to trying to perform an action.  You should make sure that the page is completely done loading before you try to click the reset button.